# The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<string>'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting this error in angular's autocomplete example. Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(val => this.filter(val))
          );
}
```

The error is spawn on startWith. I am also getting an error in the second val. It says:

> Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

The function is:

```
 filter(val: string): string[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }
```

**HINT:**
There is something with mixed controls or imports. I am not sure but when I create a new component everything works fine.

Comment: Would you please show the full code for the function the error is in?

Comment: Seems like myControl is not a control, it's a FormGroup? Because then valueChanges would emit objects instead of strings.

Answer (score 107):

I just had the same issue and it turns out I was importing map and startWith from the wrong directory.

```
import {map, startWith} from "rxjs/operators";
```

Use this to import both map and startWith and it should work and compile.

Comment: Same issue here -> import { delay } from 'rxjs/operator/delay'; instead of import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators/delay';

Answer (score 0):

My case was that I loaded `take(1)` automatically by autopopulating from `rxjs/compat/take` but not from `rxjs/operators`, and catch this issue. Not so obvious thing :)